# What's the advantages of pre-fetching the GraphQL schema when we can manually pass data to request body?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, nestjs, schema

Foreword: I am completely new to GraphQL so I am just trying to figure out what is the best practice when working with it

So I need to call a GraphQL API written in Nestjs (more specifically, from a Rails server).
There is this nice gem [graphql-client](https://github.com/github/graphql-client) that makes a `Client` to communicate with GraphQL API.
In order for it to work, it needs a `Schema` **before** initializing the `Client`. It also suggest that we should fetch the schema and dump it into a file **before** initializing the `Client`

I also notice that, when I paste the GraphQL URL to postman, it pre-fetch the schema.

A quick code snippet worked. But later I found out that I can just use an API gem (like `HTTParty`) and make a `POST` request with correct body in order to call the GraphQL API

I thought: "maybe I should investigate how other JS tools work with GraphQL because Rails may behave differently". I then read [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/5-ways-to-fetch-data-react-graphql/). In short, we can just use an API library (like `axios`) to make request to the GraphQL server, without the need or pre-fetching schema.

My questions is: Why do we need to pre-fetch the schema before making request? What is the advantages of that? If there is any articles I should read in order to have a better understanding of this, please kindly provide me.

Answer (score 1):

You should never need to fetch the schema at *runtime*. It can however be useful to fetch the schema to define *types* on the client that match what the server is going to send you when you request data at runtime.